# Noun for something that is obvious

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, uncountable-nouns

I think I have known this word before, but it has completely slipped my mind. It will be a bit hard to tell you what word I'm talking about, but I will try as good as I can.

Consider these sentences

> I'm your older brother, it is **obvious** that I will kick your ass.

Now, the sentence I want to use doesn't use an adjective where **obvious** is placed. It uses a noun.

> I'm your older brother, it is a/an (...) that I will kick your ass.

I'm going to give an example of this with words that I know exist.

> I'm your older brother, it is **inevitable** that I will kick your ass.

But the sentence I want is-

> I'm your older brother, it is **an inevitability** that I will kick your ass.

So, I want the noun, not the adjective. I don't think there is a noun form of **obvious**, though I don't need that either. I just need a noun that fits my description.

Hopefully this wasn't too complicated, but I often struggle to illustrate what I'm talking about when it comes these kinds of questions.

Comment: In case it helps your search, consider ***foregone conclusion*** or ***certainty***

Comment: @JimMack That means exactly what I'm talking about! Only I was looking for a single word, but I'm heavily considering this option, as it works quite well. But if there's a single word that means this, that would be best, as it would make the sentence flow better. At least in my opinion, but many thanks!

Comment: @JimMack You should make your comment an answer, because I was actually looking for exactly the word "certainty". Thank you very much for a quick reply.

Comment: In colloquial terms it’s ***a given***

Comment: Thomas Jefferson would hold "these truths" to be self-evident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A phrase that fits would be ***[foregone conclusion](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/foregone%20conclusion)***, which also has the definition ***certainty***. (M/W)

Answer (score 1):

**"it's a fact"** comes to mind.

I'm your older brother, **it is a fact that I will kick your ass.**

> - [**fact**](https://www.google.com.br/search?safe=off&rlz=1C1ARAB_enBR495BR495&q=Dictionary#dobs=fact) (noun) - "a thing that is indisputably the case."

Of course it would sound more categorical if you placed an adjective before "fact"

"I'm your older brother, it is **an unmistakable fact** that I will kick your ass."

Comment: Every time I hear the word *facts* I can’t help but think of Kellyanne Conway’s ***alternative** facts*!

Comment: @k1eran She was a laughing stock.